# How can I make Scanner.next(); return any datatype in BlueJ?

Tags: java, object, bluej

I have got a class (`"testClass"`) containing a method. This class has three objects. Now I want to call the methods of those objects by entering a command in the BlueJ terminal. I read the commands with Scanner.next(). If I enter `Object1`, the method of `Object1` should be called. The problem is, that `Scanner.next()` returns `String`, so

```
testClass Object = Scanner.next();
Object.testMethod();
```

doesn't work. I get the error

> "Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to testMethod.

I don't want to make something like this too:

```
String command = Scanner.next();
switch(command){
    case "object1": object1.testMethod();

    case "object2": object2.testMethod();

    ...


}
```

How can I get it working?

Comment: As to your title question, you literally can't, short of re-writing the Java platform.

Comment: Well you can't. your reading a line which java says is a String (which makes sense). also you should use some standard naming conventions of Java like Classes start with an uppercase and variables don't

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make Scanner.next(); return any datatype in BlueJ?

You can't.  What you can do is write something that converts the `String` into a command invocation.

> I don't want to make something like this [switch code] too:

It sounds like you want to implement something like the Command pattern here.
Here's a (very) simple example of how to do that in Java:

```
// This is a simple way to have a list of commands to run.
// It also gives you a very easy way to map a String to a command behavior,
// to read console commands or menu headings or something like that.
// You could also have your command invoker catch the exception and display
// a "this action is unsupported" message.

public class CommandPatternExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CommandEnum.valueOf("A").execute(); // run command "A"
        CommandEnum.valueOf("B").execute(); // run command "B"
        CommandEnum.valueOf("C").execute(); // IllegalArgumentException
    }

    interface Command {
        void execute();
    }

    enum CommandEnum implements Command {
        A {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Running command A");
            }
        },
        B {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Running command B");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to do this. Polymorphism can help you here.

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void testMethod();
}

class ChildA extends A {
    @Override
    void testMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        A obj = (A) Class.forName("ChildA").newInstance();
        obj.testMethod();
    }
}
```

You can also you `Scanner` here to get the class name from the user at runtime.